# WCF RIA service return data not matching on the 2 sides of the service

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I originally thought this was a INotifyPropertyChanged/Binding issue because I'm not sure how to debug the silverlight part. So I had to put a messagebox in a foreach loop and view the values after the data returned that way. It turns out that I'm having trouble getting the updated data from the service. I use the service to do some updates to data on the server and when it gets back call to reload the data. This part of the service is returning the correct data (I verified using a breakpoint so I could look at the data result was holding). But the silverlight side is not getting the right data. Here is the relevant code.

```
public IQueryable<OurClass> GetItems(string condition)
{
    var result   = from items in context.OurClass 
                   where item.value == condition  
                   select item;

    return result; //had my breakpoint here and the values were the correct updated values
}
```

/

```
Context.Load<OurClass>(Context.GetItemsQuery(condition)).Completed += new EventHandler(Context_LoadCompleted);
```

/

```
private void Context_LoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<OurClass> result = ((LoadOperation<OurClass>)sender).Entities;
    //This is where I put a MessageBox to view the returned results and the data was different
    //than what was contained in the other result
}
```

Any ideas what could cause this? What should I look at next?

**EDIT:**

Some example data is OurClass.OurProperty will equal "Test" on the server side but once it is received on the client it will equal "Development" which was the old value. The IEnumerable will hold the newly added records and not have the deleted ones. Any that previously existed will contain the old property values and not the new values.

Comment: One reason the data can be different is if the Key column on several items are the same. If you are returning a set of `OurClass` and the key column is an `int`, make sure that each item returned has a unique `int` for it's key. (Check this on the service side, not the consumer side.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Key column. Our primary key is the Id property and its a Guid. By default they can't be the same obviously so that must not be what you are talking about. I'll investigate this tomorrow as well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Each data transfer object as a Key (denoted by the `[Key]` attribute on the property. If you are using EF, this key is generated for you from the database. Look at the class definition for `OurClass` and determine which property is marked as `[Key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to add the parameter LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent to the query call. So this:

```
Context.Load<OurClass>(Context.GetItemsQuery(condition)).Completed += new EventHandler(Context_LoadCompleted);
```

Needed to be this:

```
Context.Load<OurClass>(Context.GetItemsQuery(condition), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, true).Completed += new EventHandler(Context_LoadCompleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the data different on each side of the service? can you show us some example data. You can have a look at data using something like wireshark (will need to be on the server, or on your client where you are running your silverlight applet from.)

Have you tried debugging your silverlight properly, ie attach to the process as shown here: http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/04/22/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-2-attach-to-process-debugging/

I would also recommend turning on WCF tracing as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I'll look into your links. Thank you. I updated my post with a bit more of a description of the data I expect and what I get.

Comment: I got the silverlight debugging working finally. Had followed similar procedures before but never saw a process that said "silverlight" for me to attach to. Realize now that was because I was already attached automatically in script mode. Only figured that out because I accidentally opened that Attach to Process window in the wrong Visual Studio instance and saw the silverlight tag on that process. Now I'm going to have to look into the WCF tracing tomorrow to see why the values on the receiving end are not the same as on the sending side.